# Is the BlockingCollection thread-safe?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asp.net-core, thread-safety

```
BlockingCollection<int> blockingCollection = new BlockingCollection<int>();
    // create and start a producer
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
        // put items into the collectioon
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            blockingCollection.Add(i);
        }
        // mark the collection as complete
        blockingCollection.CompleteAdding();
    });
    // create and start a producer
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
        while (!blockingCollection.IsCompleted)
        {
            // take an item from the collection
            int item = blockingCollection.Take();
            // print out the item
            Console.WriteLine("Taskid{1} Item {0}", item, Task.CurrentId);
        }
    });

    // create and start a producer
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
        while (!blockingCollection.IsCompleted)   // if the blockingCollection is not completed
        {
            // take an item from the collection
            int item = blockingCollection.Take();  // but in here, all the items have been taken by other thread, this line will wait forever?
            // print out the item
            Console.WriteLine("Taskid{1} Item {0}", item,Task.CurrentId);
        }
    });
    Console.ReadLine();
```

Key lines of code:

```
    while (!blockingCollection.IsCompleted)   // if the blockingCollection is not completed
    int item = blockingCollection.Take();  // but in here, all the items have been taken by other thread, this line will wait forever?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Question 1 - Is it thread safe?

Quoting the [BlockingCollection documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1?view=netframework-4.8)

> Provides blocking and bounding capabilities for **thread-safe** collections that implement IProducerConsumerCollection.

### Question 2 - Will `Take()`, take forever?

From the official documentation: [MS Docs on blocking collection - Take](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1.take?view=netframework-4.8)

> `OperationCanceledException`
>
> The BlockingCollection is empty and has been marked as complete with regards to additions.

So when `Take` is called on a Completed `BlockingCollection` an exception will be thrown, that you can handle accordingly

Answer (score 4):

Yes, `BlockingCollection<T>` is *thread safe*.

In order to avoid `IsCompleted` checking you can put the same logic with a help of `GetConsumingEnumerable()` which will wait until blocking collection completion:

```
  // Producer:

  Task.Run(() => { 
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
      blockingCollection.Add(i);

    blockingCollection.CompleteAdding();
  });    

  // Consumers:

  Task.Run(() => {
    foreach (var item in blockingCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable()) 
      Console.WriteLine("Taskid{1} Item {0}", item, Task.CurrentId);
  });

  Task.Run(() => {
    foreach (var item in blockingCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable()) 
      Console.WriteLine("Taskid{1} Item {0}", item, Task.CurrentId);
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`BlockingCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1) class *is* thread safe, in the sense that its internal state is protected from corruption when called concurrently by multiple threads. It is *not* thread safe in the sense that its mere presence blesses with thread safety a thread-unsafe block of code!

Your code is unsafe because between the calls to `IsCompleted` and `Take`, another thread could call the `Complete` method and change the state of the `BlockingCollection` from non-completed to completed. A thread safe solution would be to use an API that combines `IsCompleted` and `Take` in an atomic operation. There is no such API in the `BlockingCollection` class, but you can achieve what you want with the [`GetConsumingEnumerable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1.getconsumingenumerable) method. This method returns an `IEnumerable` that blocks while waiting for available items, and completes when the `BlockingCollection` completes. Actually this is the standard and preferred way for consuming this collection.